# How do I select Sensor using chip 74HC138 on Wemos D1 Mini?

Tags: esp8266, sensors, temperature-sensor

I have a project for my graduate degree.

It's about Monitoring Temperature and Humidity using Message Queuing Telemetry Transport on Serial NodeJS. To get sensor data to Wemos D1 Mini and NodeJS had done, also on my MQTT had done. My lecturer wants to get data from two sensors at the edges of the room, he suggests using a 74HC138. I'm using this [74HC138 Datasheet](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT138.pdf) and I'm using this [BME280 Library](https://github.com/SV-Zanshin/BME280).

This is my schematic:

[image: Schematic]

This is my code:

```
#include <BME280.h>

const uint32_t SERIAL_SPEED = 115200;
const uint8_t SCK_PIN = D5;
const uint8_t MISO_PIN = D6;
const uint8_t MOSI_PIN = D7;
const uint8_t SPI_CS1_PIN = 15;
const uint8_t SPI_CS2_PIN = 14;
const uint8_t GPIO[3] = {D1, D2, D3};

static int32_t temperature, humidity, pressure;
int i;

BME280_Class   BME280;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(SERIAL_SPEED);
  pinMode(SCK_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MOSI_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MISO_PIN, INPUT);

  SPI.begin();
  SPI.setBitOrder(LSBFIRST);

  Serial.println(F("condition before loop = "));
  //status_pin();
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    pinMode(GPIO[i], INPUT);
    digitalWrite(GPIO[i], HIGH);
  }
  pinMode(SPI_CS1_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SPI_CS2_PIN, OUTPUT);

  Serial.println(F("Starting Hardware SPIDemo example program for BME280"));
  Serial.print(F("- Initializing BME280 sensor\n"));

  if ( (!BME280.begin(SPI_CS1_PIN) && (!BME280.begin(SPI_CS2_PIN) ) {
    Serial.println(F("-  Unable to find BME280. Waiting 3 seconds."));
    delay(3000);
  }

  BME280.mode(SleepMode);
  Serial.print(F("- Sensor detected in operating mode \""));
  Serial.print(BME280.mode());
  Serial.println(F("\"."));
  if (BME280.mode() == 0) {
    Serial.print(F("- Turning sensor to normal mode, mode is now \""));
    Serial.print(BME280.mode(NormalMode));
    Serial.println("\"");
  }
  Serial.println(F("- Setting 16x oversampling for all sensors"));
  BME280.setOversampling(TemperatureSensor, Oversample16);
  BME280.setOversampling(HumiditySensor,   Oversample16);
  BME280.setOversampling(PressureSensor,   Oversample16);
  Serial.println(F("- Setting IIR filter to maximum value of 16 samples"));
  BME280.iirFilter(IIR16);
  Serial.println(F("- Setting time between measurements to 1 second"));
  BME280.inactiveTime(inactive1000ms);
  Serial.print(F("- Each measurement cycle will take "));
  Serial.print(BME280.measurementTime(MaximumMeasure) / 1000);
  Serial.println(F("ms.\n\n"));
}

void loop() {
  static uint8_t loopCounter = 0;
  byte pin1 = 0x74;
  byte pin2 = 0x71;

  if ( BME280.begin(SPI_CS1_PIN) == 1 ) {
    selpin(pin1);
    Serial.println(F(" Data Bme = "));
  } else if ( BME280.begin(SPI_CS2_PIN) == 1 ) {
    selpin(pin2);
    Serial.println(F(" Data Bme = "));
    printdata();
  }

  if (++loopCounter % 10 == 0) {
    Serial.print(F("\n- Turning "));
    if (BME280.getOversampling(HumiditySensor) == 0) {
      BME280.setOversampling(HumiditySensor, Oversample16);
      Serial.print(F("ON"));
    } else  {
      BME280.setOversampling(HumiditySensor, SensorOff);
      Serial.print(F("OFF"));
    }
    Serial.println(F(" humidity sensing"));
    Serial.print(F("- Each measurement cycle will now take "));
    Serial.print(BME280.measurementTime(MaximumMeasure) / 1000.0);
    Serial.println(F("ms.\n"));
  }

  Serial.println(F("condition after loop = "));
  //status_pin();
  Serial.println();

}

float altitude(const float seaLevel = 1013.25) {
  int32_t temp, hum, press;
  BME280.getSensorData(temp, hum, press);
  float Altitude = 44330.0 * (1.0 - pow(((float)press / 100.0) / seaLevel, 0.1903));
  return (Altitude);
}

void printdata () {
  BME280.getSensorData(temperature, humidity, pressure);
  Serial.print(F("Temperature : "));
  Serial.print(temperature / 100.0);
  Serial.println(F(" *C"));
  if (BME280.getOversampling(HumiditySensor) != 0) {
    Serial.print(F("Humidity : "));
    Serial.print(humidity / 100.0);
    Serial.println(F(" %"));
  }
  Serial.print(F("Pressure : "));
  Serial.print(pressure / 100.0);
  Serial.println(F(" hPa"));
  Serial.print(F("Altitude : "));
  Serial.print(altitude());
  Serial.println(F(" m"));
  Serial.println();
  delay(5000);
}
```

Serial output always says `Unable to find BME280. Waiting 3 seconds.` I know it's because `CS` pin cannot detect. I think something is missing my code.

**SOLVED**

Thanks to my pal @Majenko, I'm out of the 74HC138 stock but i have 74HC139, i think that's same to me, i tried advice from @Majenko early morning after i make assembly of my board own for define Chip Select Wemos to my enable pin and get back my missing code whom not understand me.

**See below** for verbose log of uploading my sketch.

[image]

**See below** for serial monitor.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a 74HC138 in this situation is both pointless and wasteful. You're using 3 pins (or 4 - see below) to drive a chip to select between 2 pins. That's wasting one more pin than you would by directly driving the CS pins.

The only time it would make sense would be if you were wanting to connect with 5 or more devices, in which case you would get a saving in the number of pins used.

Anyway - what you are missing from your code is absolutely everything to do with the 74HC138. First off, you're using a library which assumes the CS pins are directly connected to the MCU. Second, there is no code to set the A/B/C pins to the right state to select an output.

If you really *must* use the 74HC138 I would suggest:

- Use the same CS pin in your code for every BMS280 instance.
- Connect that CS pin to G2A on the 74HC138
- Use the following procedure to access a sensor:

  1. Select the correct output on the 74HC138 by setting the A/B/C pins to the binary representation of the output you want
  2. Perform the BME280 operations you want on the relevant instance

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faxEwM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The CS pin you passed to the BME280 instances will control the state of the currently selected output on the 74HC138, turning it into a demultiplexer controlled by the A/B/C pins.  Using multiple instances of the BME280 class associated with each selected output will allow proper tracking of any internal state and data associated with the device connected to that output.

Or, and this is just throwing ideas out there, don't use the 74HC138 and tell your "lecturer" that it's a stupid idea to use 3 pins (4 including the chip select pin) to control a pair of devices that need a total of 2 pins.

Comment: i'm still little confuse sir, your mean "Connect that CS pin to Q2A on the 74HC138" i must connect CS to enable input pin and where i must connect Y1-Y2 output pin? where i can find example of send the binary representation to chip. i really noob about chip gate sir

Comment: Sorry, that's a G on your little picture, not a Q.  Looks the same to me.  You don't "send" the binary representation to the chip. You set your three pins connected to A/B/C to that binary representation. Output 0 is LOW/LOW/LOW.  Output 1 is HIGH/LOW/LOW. Output 2 is LOW/HIGH/LOW, Output 3 is HIGH/HIGH/LOW, etc.  Outputs go as they are now.

Comment: yes that's G, it's fine, ok i can see what do you mean on your picture, to set A/B/C pin what i must using `pinMode` or `digitalWrite` sir?

Comment: Both. `pinMode` to set them as outputs, and `digitalWrite` to set the logic levels.

Comment: hello again my pal, if my lecture want to set enable pin as low, which one i do declare CS pin to my 74hc139 sir? i didn't get option anything.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking (language barrier).

Comment: sorry my bad, if my lecturer want to connect enable pin to gnd as active low, how i do connect cs pin in wemos to IC 74hc139 sir?

Comment: With a wire? I still don't understand what you want.

Comment: yes with a wire, if `GA` pin to `GND` pin as active low , how i do initialize `CS` pin in wemos to IC ?

Comment: The bme280 library should be doing all that for you

Comment: if i define `D8` pin, where i must connect to 74hc138 in order to get data?

Comment: G2A as I have shown in my schematic.

Comment: if i connect `D8` pin to `G2A` pin whether it is active low

Comment: G2A and G2B are active low. G1 is active high. All three need to be active for the chip to operate.

Comment: is it `D8` pin becomes active low?

Comment: Outputs don't have a concept of "active", only a currently selected level. If you use D8 in the begin function to a BME280 object then the BME280 code will drive it low for you when it needs to.

Comment: if i connect `G2A` pin to `GND` pin as active low, how i use `D8` pin to make the begin function?

Comment: The wemos connects it to ground for you. You don't connect it to ground. D8, when low, connects the pin to ground.

Comment: i see now, a voted for you!!