# My verbose appears "unable to cache built core"

Tags: esp8266, core-libraries

At early morning i have accidentally the error of GNOME for my OS, so I was forced reinstall my OS couse i don't have any backup for my packages and my database. i'm installed Arduino-IDE 1.8.7, Arduino AVR Boards 1.6.23 and Esp8266 Boards 2.4.2 . when i trying to upload my sketch, i get this error:

```
...
Unable to cache built core, please tell esp8266 maintainers to follow http://goo.gl/QdCUjo
...
```

I see the link, but i cannot see where my archive variable in platform file for my cores.

```
...
## Create archives
recipe.ar.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.ar.cmd}" {compiler.ar.flags} {compiler.ar.extra_flags} "{build.path}/arduino.ar" "{object_file}"
...
```

**See** my verbose [log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2n6GVkgM3m/) !!!.

```
/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-ar cru /tmp/arduino_build_988288/arduino.ar /tmp/arduino_build_988288/core/spiffs_api.cpp.o
/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-ar cru /tmp/arduino_build_988288/arduino.ar /tmp/arduino_build_988288/core/spiffs_hal.cpp.o
/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-ar cru /tmp/arduino_build_988288/arduino.ar /tmp/arduino_build_988288/core/time.c.o
/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-ar cru /tmp/arduino_build_988288/arduino.ar /tmp/arduino_build_988288/core/uart.c.o
/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-ar cru /tmp/arduino_build_988288/arduino.ar /tmp/arduino_build_988288/core/umm_malloc/umm_malloc.c.o
Unable to cache built core, please tell esp8266 maintainers to follow http://goo.gl/QdCUjo
Linking everything together...
/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc -CC -E -P -DVTABLES_IN_FLASH /home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/tools/sdk/ld/eagle.app.v6.common.ld.h -o /home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/tools/sdk/ld/eagle.app.v6.common.ld
/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc -Wl,-Map -Wl,/tmp/arduino_build_988288/tesHC139.ino.map -g -w -Os -nostdlib -Wl,--no-check-sections -u app_entry -u _printf_float -u _scanf_float -Wl,-static -L/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/tools/sdk/lib -L/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/tools/sdk/ld -L/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib -Teagle.flash.4m1m.ld -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-wrap,system_restart_local -Wl,-wrap,spi_flash_read -o /tmp/arduino_build_988288/tesHC139.ino.elf -Wl,--start-group /tmp/arduino_build_988288/sketch/tesHC139.ino.cpp.o /tmp/arduino_build_988288/libraries/SPI/SPI.cpp.o /tmp/arduino_build_988288/libraries/Adafruit_BME280_Library-master/Adafruit_BME280.cpp.o /tmp/arduino_build_988288/libraries/Wire/Wire.cpp.o /tmp/arduino_build_988288/arduino.ar -lhal -lphy -lpp -lnet80211 -llwip2 -lwpa -lcrypto -lmain -lwps -lbearssl -laxtls -lespnow -lsmartconfig -lairkiss -lwpa2 -lstdc++ -lm -lc -lgcc -Wl,--end-group -L/tmp/arduino_build_988288
/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/esptool/0.4.13/esptool -eo /home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/bootloaders/eboot/eboot.elf -bo /tmp/arduino_build_988288/tesHC139.ino.bin -bm dio -bf 40 -bz 4M -bs .text -bp 4096 -ec -eo /tmp/arduino_build_988288/tesHC139.ino.elf -bs .irom0.text -bs .text -bs .data -bs .rodata -bc -ec
Using library SPI at version 1.0 in folder: /home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/libraries/SPI 
Using library Adafruit_Sensor-master at version 1.0.2 in folder: /home/praz/Arduino/libraries/Adafruit_Sensor-master 
Using library Adafruit_BME280_Library-master at version 1.0.7 in folder: /home/praz/Arduino/libraries/Adafruit_BME280_Library-master 
Using library Wire at version 1.0 in folder: /home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/libraries/Wire 
/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-size -A /tmp/arduino_build_988288/tesHC139.ino.elf
Sketch uses 259408 bytes (24%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
Global variables use 28352 bytes (34%) of dynamic memory, leaving 53568 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/esptool/0.4.13/esptool -vv -cd nodemcu -cb 115200 -cp /dev/ttyUSB0 -ca 0x00000 -cf /tmp/arduino_build_988288/tesHC139.ino.bin
```

I don't think so if i have permissions issue, it seems my boards is fine about my permissions.

```
total 388
drwxrwxr-x  8 praz praz   4096 Okt 11 00:14 ./
drwxrwxr-x  3 praz praz   4096 Okt 11 00:13 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 praz praz 293575 Agu  3 14:19 boards.txt
drwxrwxr-x  3 praz praz   4096 Agu  3 14:19 bootloaders/
drwxrwxr-x  3 praz praz   4096 Agu  3 14:19 cores/
-rw-rw-r--  1 praz praz    235 Agu  3 14:19 .gitmodules
-rw-rw-r--  1 praz praz   2831 Agu  3 14:19 ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 praz praz    553 Agu  3 14:19 keywords.txt
drwxrwxr-x 28 praz praz   4096 Agu  3 14:19 libraries/
-rw-rw-r--  1 praz praz  26529 Agu  3 14:19 LICENSE
-rw-rw-r--  1 praz praz    194 Agu  3 14:19 package.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 praz praz   6844 Agu  3 14:19 platform.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 praz praz   7136 Agu  3 14:19 POLICY.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 praz praz      0 Agu  3 14:19 programmers.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 praz praz   7722 Agu  3 14:19 README.md
drwxrwxr-x  4 praz praz   4096 Agu  3 14:19 tests/
drwxrwxr-x  3 praz praz   4096 Agu  3 14:19 tools/
drwxrwxr-x 25 praz praz   4096 Agu  3 14:19 variants/
```

**Solved**

I think when i installed Esp8266 Boards 2.4.2 latest version is fine, i uploaded my sketch and i cannot make cache to my built core, Majenko is right, my the snippet of config are difference between my [74hc139](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/55938/how-do-i-select-sensor-using-chip-74hc138-on-wemos-d1-mini) issue and my [verbose log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2n6GVkgM3m/) issue.

when i installed fresh Esp8266 Boards using boards manager, that automatically downloads source code of esp8266 core on this [Github](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino), i don't understand why my snippet of config not updated like this [commit](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/commit/85e68093e94b4e5c5e711888b8b5facee1bd4f9f#diff-d638a47d1ca0e2a5585fb34c7d7fb0f9L95). so i updated my config of boards with copy/paste on tree links of  [Github](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/85e68093e94b4e5c5e711888b8b5facee1bd4f9f), and that's works.

See my verbose below or see at [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZwKXXCd4gg/) :

```
/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-ar cru /tmp/arduino_build_979295/core/core.a /tmp/arduino_build_979295/core/sqrt32.c.o
/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-ar cru /tmp/arduino_build_979295/core/core.a /tmp/arduino_build_979295/core/time.c.o
/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-ar cru /tmp/arduino_build_979295/core/core.a /tmp/arduino_build_979295/core/uart.c.o
/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-ar cru /tmp/arduino_build_979295/core/core.a /tmp/arduino_build_979295/core/umm_malloc/umm_malloc.c.o
Archiving built core (caching) in: /tmp/arduino_cache_39139/core/core_8e365e854c5bfceaa27f4c371ba290d0.a
Linking everything together...
/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc -CC -E -P -DVTABLES_IN_FLASH /home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/tools/sdk/ld/eagle.app.v6.common.ld.h -o /tmp/arduino_build_979295/local.eagle.app.v6.common.ld
/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc -Wl,-Map -Wl,/tmp/arduino_build_979295/tesHC139.ino.map -g -Wall -Wextra -Os -nostdlib -Wl,--no-check-sections -u app_entry -u _printf_float -u _scanf_float -Wl,-static -L/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/tools/sdk/lib -L/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/tools/sdk/ld -L/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib -Teagle.flash.4m.ld -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-wrap,system_restart_local -Wl,-wrap,spi_flash_read -o /tmp/arduino_build_979295/tesHC139.ino.elf -Wl,--start-group /tmp/arduino_build_979295/sketch/tesHC139.ino.cpp.o /tmp/arduino_build_979295/libraries/SPI/SPI.cpp.o /tmp/arduino_build_979295/libraries/Adafruit_BME280_Library-master/Adafruit_BME280.cpp.o /tmp/arduino_build_979295/libraries/Wire/Wire.cpp.o /tmp/arduino_build_979295/core/core.a -lhal -lphy -lpp -lnet80211 -llwip2-536-feat -lwpa -lcrypto -lmain -lwps -lbearssl -laxtls -lespnow -lsmartconfig -lairkiss -lwpa2 -lstdc++ -lm -lc -lgcc -Wl,--end-group -L/tmp/arduino_build_979295
/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/tools/esptool/esptool -eo /home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/bootloaders/eboot/eboot.elf -bo /tmp/arduino_build_979295/tesHC139.ino.bin -bm dio -bf 40 -bz 4M -bs .text -bp 4096 -ec -eo /tmp/arduino_build_979295/tesHC139.ino.elf -bs .irom0.text -bs .text -bs .data -bs .rodata -bc -ec
Using library SPI at version 1.0 in folder: /home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/libraries/SPI 
Using library Adafruit_Sensor-master at version 1.0.2 in folder: /home/praz/Arduino/libraries/Adafruit_Sensor-master 
Using library Adafruit_BME280_Library-master at version 1.0.7 in folder: /home/praz/Arduino/libraries/Adafruit_BME280_Library-master 
Using library Wire at version 1.0 in folder: /home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/libraries/Wire 
/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-size -A /tmp/arduino_build_979295/tesHC139.ino.elf
Sketch uses 265524 bytes (25%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
Global variables use 28236 bytes (34%) of dynamic memory, leaving 53684 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
/home/praz/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.4.2/tools/esptool/esptool -vv -cd nodemcu -cb 115200 -cp /dev/ttyUSB0 -ca 0x00000 -cf /tmp/arduino_build_979295/tesHC139.ino.bin
```

Hope anyone can solve my issue, Thanks in advance.

Comment: turn on in Preferences the verbose output for console. you will see the path

Comment: @Juraj i turn on at my command line absolutely.

Comment: You may have some file permission errors in tour home directory. Check ownership.

Comment: Juraj i'm on my Ubuntu, Majenko i don't think so i have permissions issue.

Comment: Juraj Majenko see my verbose http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2n6GVkgM3m/

Comment: The snippet of config you show doesn't match with what is currently in the Github repo for the ESP8266 core. Make sure you have the latest version of the core installed.

Comment: @Majenko you're right, i see my verbose on 74h138 chip issue and this verbose have difference xtensa tools, i just update my source code of tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed on the 20th August in [this commit](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/commit/85e68093e94b4e5c5e711888b8b5facee1bd4f9f#diff-d638a47d1ca0e2a5585fb34c7d7fb0f9L95). Make sure you have the latest version of the ESP8266 core installed. If there hasn't been a release since that fix, you can pull the github version of the config file and use that instead of the one bundled with the core.

However, it's not a fatal error - it merely means that compilation will be slower than it should be.

Comment: Thanks, i think so, i found it too, i still editing before.